# Is there a way to run an action on a grammar that's already been parsed?

Tags: grammar, raku

If I do:

```
my $parsed_grammar = PG.parse( $some_string );
```

Is there any way to to do something like the pseudo code below?

```
$parsed_grammar.run_action( $action_class.new );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Your grammar is basically a program.

Contrary to other (regex) implementations, Raku grammars are basically just another way to write a class and methods.  It's all code underneath.  Code that can have callbacks for each method run. That's what your action class is: a way to specify the callbacks.

So, the parsing of your grammar happens at **compile time**.  That creates code that gets run when you call `.parse` with the given string as the input.

Your misconception seems to be that running `.parse` on a grammar parses the grammar.  It doesn't.  It **runs** the grammar, it *parses* your *input string*.